# numpy masked smoothing algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have a smoothing algorithm that I implemented that basically applies a kernel:

```
 [0 1 0;
  1 4 1;
  0 1 0]/8
```

to a matrix (image) and then corrects the edges and corners, equivalent to setting the kernel as

```
 [0 1 0;
  0 5 1;
  0 1 0]/8
```

for a left edge, and

```
 [0 0 0; 
  0 6 1; 
  0 1 0]/8
```

for a top-left corner.

My goal now is to apply a smoothing that only applies to a masked part of that image. For example (refer to images below), if I had a square image of a disk, where the disk would have values of 128+-10 (+-10 is a noise effect), and the background is black (value of 0), the normal smoothing algorithm applied infinite times should give a square image with a constant pixel intensity. For the masked smoothing algorithm I would like to mask the disk such that the algorithm applied infinite times should give a uniform disk at 128 and a black (0) background. In other words, only the disk was smoothed.

The main thing that I'm trying to avoid is that the background "bleeds" into the disk, making the edges of the disk fuzzy. I'm also willing to change the smoothing algorithm to something different (eg. average of 3x3 pixels) that would allow for a more efficient approach.

[image: NoisyOriginal]( Noisy Original )

[image: Standard Smooth] (After the normal smooth)

[image: MakedSmooth]( After the masked smooth )

Here is my code for normal smooth:

```
def SmoothImage(Matrix,N=1):
    '''Smooths a Matrix with kernel [0 1 0; 1 4 1; 0 1 0]/8'''
    A=Matrix.copy()
    for i in range(N):
        s=A.shape[0]-1
        B=A*4.0
        B[-s:,:]+=A[:s,:]
        B[0,:]+=A[0,:]
        B[:,-s:]+=A[:,:s]
        B[:,0]+=A[:,0]

        B[:s,:]+=A[-s:,:]
        B[-1,:]+=A[-1,:]
        B[:,:s]+=A[:,-s:]
        B[:,-1]+=A[:,-1]
        B*=1/8
        A=B
    return A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using linear convolution plus some trickery to preserve clean edges. The trickery basically computes the mass lost at the edges by convolving with the inverse mask and adds it to the raw result:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

kernel = np.add.outer(*2*(np.arange(3) % 2,))**2 / 8

def perfect_edges(orig, n_iter=1, thresh=20):
    mask = orig <= thresh
    corrector = convolve2d(mask, kernel, 'same')
    result = orig.copy()
    result[mask] = 0
    for j in range(n_iter):
        result = result * corrector + convolve2d(result, kernel, 'same')
        result[mask] = 0
    result = np.round(result).astype(np.uint8)
    result[mask] = orig[mask]
    return result

picture = (np.add.outer(*2*(np.arange(-6, 7)**2,)) < 30).view(np.uint8) * 118
picture += np.random.randint(0, 21, picture.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

print(picture)
print()
print(perfect_edges(picture, 200))
```

Sample run:

```
[[ 15   0   4  10  17  13  20  12  14   1   5  16  19]
 [  1   6   9  14 132 132 129 128 135   1   5  11   5]
 [ 13  16   6 126 118 118 134 120 130 138   2   6  10]
 [ 16   3 129 129 128 129 125 134 131 132 127  18   8]
 [ 10 120 132 125 128 120 133 137 125 120 124 129   7]
 [ 10 137 119 120 119 118 137 135 135 126 118 128   0]
 [ 17 134 138 133 134 121 124 119 134 138 133 129   2]
 [  3 134 136 132 119 124 123 133 126 121 126 122  19]
 [  3 123 130 123 125 125 128 119 119 129 119 127   6]
 [  5   0 119 118 125 122 135 135 126 133 136   7   3]
 [ 11   1  13 124 121 118 136 137 127 137   2  19  15]
 [  6   7  15  19 132 132 130 125 130   9  18   9  12]
 [ 16  20   0  14   9  10   1   6   5  17  16   0   3]]

[[ 15   0   4  10  17  13  20  12  14   1   5  16  19]
 [  1   6   9  14 128 128 128 128 128   1   5  11   5]
 [ 13  16   6 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   2   6  10]
 [ 16   3 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128  18   8]
 [ 10 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   7]
 [ 10 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   0]
 [ 17 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   2]
 [  3 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128  19]
 [  3 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   6]
 [  5   0 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   7   3]
 [ 11   1  13 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   2  19  15]
 [  6   7  15  19 128 128 128 128 128   9  18   9  12]
 [ 16  20   0  14   9  10   1   6   5  17  16   0   3]]
```

Comment: This works really well. I was just thinking: Wouldn't `result[mask]=orig[mask]` be even more robust after the convolution? It seems that this way we could smooth inside a mask and keep the outside the same.

Comment: @Miguel at the moment mask is defined by `orig == 0`, so it would make no difference. If the "outside region" were not zero you'd have a point - **but** the algorithm wouldn't work anymore in this scenario because the outside would bleed into the inside. That said we could modify it to handle this situation as well. Let me know whether you need that feature and I'll have another look.

Comment: For my goal, with zero is enough, but I think that having with a "general background" would be amazing.

Comment: @Miguel I've modified the function. Not very deep. I just set the outside to zero in the beginning and back to its original value in the very end.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.ndimage.convolve()` is what you want. To do convolution with mask, call `convolve()` with the image and the mask, and then do the divide:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

img = np.random.rand(100, 100)

X, Y = np.mgrid[0:100, 0:100]

mask = (((X - 50)**2 + (Y - 50)**2)**0.5 < 30).astype(np.int8)

img[mask == 0] = 0

kernel = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 4, 1],
    [0, 1, 0]])

neighbour_count = ndimage.convolve(mask, kernel, mode="constant")
m = neighbour_count > 0

for i in range(10):
    img = ndimage.convolve(img, kernel, mode="constant")
    img[m] /= neighbour_count[m]
    img[mask == 0] = 0

pl.imshow(img)
```

the output:

[image]

Comment: I think your edge treatment is not equivalent to what OP's doing. For example if one neighbor is masked, they'd use central weight 5/8 and three neighbors each 1/8 whereas your method if I'm not mistaken gives 4/7 and 1/7.